# How to setup AWS Opsworks in demon mode

Tags: aws-opsworks

In AWS Opsworks, how can we setup opsworks client or chef client in demon mode.
In Chef server we can mention --demon option and run chef-client.
But, In Opsworks how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

OpsWorks works via [Chef Zero (aka Chef client in local mode)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11.html), and as such there's no Chef server.

When you do need to make a change to a custom cookbook: push it up to your custom cookbook repository. (or maybe you just refer to this cookbook in a Berksfile, then whatever).

After you've published your changes that way, you need to run [Update Cookbooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable-update.html) to have the instances download the new cookbooks.

That doesn't mean the cookbooks are run then. When they're run would depend on when the recipes are run in the [Opswork event lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-events.html).